# How do I run "vagrant up" from a context-menu in Windows?

Tags: windows, context-menu, vagrant

I have a repo with a `Vagrantfile`. I use to clone it from Mac, Linux and Win depending on the location I'm working at.

When cloning in Windows I would love to right-click the `Vagrantfile` and choose a `vagrant up` option in the context-menu, instead of having to open a `CMD`.

Questions:

- Is there any standard way to get that `vagrant` option in the windows context-menu?
- If not, is it possible to manually add an entry for the Vagrantfile only?

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom commands with [FileMenu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/filemenutools)

Click new command and you can customize it in the properties panel.